# How to emulate hyper key in Windows 10 using autohotkey

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey

I'm migrating my mac workflow to Windows. One thing I couldn't live without is hyper key which is combination of `Ctrl` + `Option` + `Shift` + `Cmd`. I use **Karabiner** app to remap `Capslock` to this `Hyper` key. I have heard that **Autohotkey** is an *Karabiner alternative for Windows*. Could you guys please help me to emulate this feature in Windows.

My ideal result is:

- Deactivate `Capslock` completely because I rarely use this
- Toggle `Capslock` will perform `ESC` key
- Hold down `Capslock` will perform `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `Shift` + `Windows`. For example `Capslock + C` will be `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Windows+C`

Many thanks in advance!

In the attempt of solving my problem, I wrote some lines of code but it doesn't work at all. Please help me point out my mistake:

```
;-----------------------------------------
; hyper key for windows
;=========================================

; --------------------------------------------------------------
; notes
; --------------------------------------------------------------
; ! = alt
; ^ = ctrl
; + = shift
; # = lwin|rwin
;
#NoEnv ; recommended for performance and compatibility with future autohotkey releases.
#UseHook
#InstallKeybdHook
#SingleInstance force

SendMode Input

;; deactivate capslock completely
SetCapslockState, AlwaysOff

;; remap capslock to hyper
;; if capslock is toggled, remap it to esc

Capslock::
    SendInput {Ctrl Down}{Alt Down}{Shift Down}{LWin Down}
    KeyWait, Capslock
    SendInput {Ctrl Up}{Alt Up}{Shift Up}{LWin Up}
    if (A_PriorKey = "Capslock") {
        SendInput {Esc}
    }
return

;; vim navigation with hyper
~^!+#h:: SendInput {Left}
~^!+#l:: SendInput {Right}
~^!+#k:: SendInput {Up}
~^!+#j:: SendInput {Down}

;; popular hotkeys with hyper
~^!+<#c:: SendInput ^{c}
~^!+<#v:: SendInput ^{v}
```

Result:

- Toggle Capslock performs ESC
- Hold Capslock performs Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Win key combination
- Hold Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Win with h,j,k,l,c,v works as expected
- **However** Hold Capslock with h,j,k,l,c,v doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to write a Autohotkey script for this?

Comment: @Seth not at the moment as I'm trying to read through Autohotkey docs. I'm trying to make my first script by tmr. I hope someone who got great knowledge of Autohotkey script would help me resolve my problem quicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for anyone trying to help me, I figured out the prob on my own and would like to share it in case anyone comes across this prob.

```
#NoEnv ; recommended for performance and compatibility with future autohotkey releases.
#UseHook
#InstallKeybdHook
#SingleInstance force

SendMode Input

;; deactivate capslock completely
SetCapslockState, AlwaysOff

;; remap capslock to hyper
;; if capslock is toggled, remap it to esc

;; note: must use tidle prefix to fire hotkey once it is pressed
;; not until the hotkey is released
~Capslock::
    ;; must use downtemp to emulate hyper key, you cannot use down in this case 
    ;; according to http://bit.ly/2fLyHHI, downtemp is as same as down except for ctrl/alt/shift/win keys
    ;; in those cases, downtemp tells subsequent sends that the key is not permanently down, and may be 
    ;; released whenever a keystroke calls for it.
    ;; for example, Send {Ctrl Downtemp} followed later by Send {Left} would produce a normal {Left}
    ;; keystroke, not a Ctrl{Left} keystroke
    Send {Ctrl DownTemp}{Shift DownTemp}{Alt DownTemp}{LWin DownTemp}
    KeyWait, Capslock
    Send {Ctrl Up}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}{LWin Up}
    if (A_PriorKey = "Capslock") {
        Send {Esc}
    }
return

;; vim navigation with hyper
~Capslock & h:: Send {Left}
~Capslock & l:: Send {Right}
~Capslock & k:: Send {Up}
~Capslock & j:: Send {Down}

;; popular hotkeys with hyper
~Capslock & c:: Send ^{c}
~Capslock & v:: Send ^{v}
```